# 2008 Thriller: Party/ Ouija Board / Girl locked in a bathroom

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

I remember watching a thriller around 2008. The parts that I remember are as follows:

A college girl and two of her friends go to a house party (I believe it was a frat house).

The girl goes upstairs where a few guests are gathering around a ouija board. She ends up using the board and the board spells out her name.

Later the girl meets a guy at the party where he ends up putting something in her drink and she passes out.

The next morning the girl wakes up in a locked white degraded bathroom on the floor (she appears to have been sexually assaulted). The screen changes to an outside view of the house which is now white and boarded up. It appears to not have been used in years. The screen shifts back to the girl who gets up and looks in the bathroom mirror. Her mirror self grins back at her.

My apologies for how general and hazy my description is. I don't remember much of the film but it gave me the spooks.

Comment: To my knowledge the movie didn't revolve around a family. Just one girl. It's not funny games I'm sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be [Left in Darkness (2006)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0466875/keywords?ref_=tt_stry_kw)

From moviepooper.com

> Celia (Monica Kenna) is celebrating her 21st birthday, feeling her
>   birthday is cursed because her mother died giving birth to her. Her
>   friend takes her to a party where one of the guys puts something in
>   her drink and proceeds to rape her with all his friends watching and
>   waiting for their turn. The guys notice she is turning blue and leave
>   her in a shower and return to the party. She dies.
>
> She awakens realizing she is still at the party and dead. The house
>   appears to be empty but she can see all the people at the party when
>   she looks in mirrors.
>
> A guy, Donovan (David Anders), shows up claiming to be her guardian
>   Angel. She spends most of the movie being chased around the house by
>   "Soul Eaters" who are able to take the shape of her Grandpa because
>   they ate his sole after he died.
>
> Donovan turns out to be a Soul Eater himself who works directly for
>   the devil and he had been guarding over her her entire life just to
>   harvest a better tasting soul from her.
>
> In the end Celia sets her grandpa's soul free and the two of them
>   climb into a dumb-waiter in the kitchen and crawl to heaven where they
>   meet up with Celia's Grandma and Mother.

Comment: This is it! I couldn't find the movie anywhere thank you.